# Last seen in Meta Stack Exchange affecting Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, profile-page, last-seen

On Sunday 14th June at around 0.30 UTC I visited some communities in Stack Exchange, but not Stack Overflow.

Yesterday I was browsing in a private session in Chrome and opened [my profile in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui?tab=profile). To my surprise, I saw that I appeared to be have been there by the time I was visiting the other communities, but not this one. I checked [my profile in Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/209901/fedorqui?tab=profile) and saw that the "last seen" was quite coincident.

[image]
[image]

However, now that I check my profile page and the "consecutive days" calendar I see that 14th of June does not appear as active:

[image]

As you see, no traces of me visiting on Sunday 14th June, contrary on what the previous image was showing.

Could it be that there is some miscommunication between the "last seen" and the "days active"? The "last seen" seems to be fetching data from Meta Stack Exchange, whereas it should not.

Comment: Visited != active. For the consecutive days metric you need to do more than just load your a page. Are you 100% certain you didn't look at a page from a google search or similar?

Comment: Not sure what page you mean, but all I did was to enter in the specific page I link in the question, always in the incognito mode. Also, from my experience, just loading the page once in a day contributed to the "consecutive" metric.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, Stack Overflow doesn't update the Last Seen value from any other site. Visiting Meta.SE does not count as a visit to Stack Overflow. Your visit times don't match *exactly*, which is what you'd expect if a visit to one was counted towards another site too.

The consecutive days metric requires more than a mere visit to count a day as active. You need to do more than that; loading any page on Stack Overflow while logged in will count as a visit, but to count as *active* you need to do more than that. What exactly, is not public to prevent gaming of the *Enthusiast* and *Fanatic* badges.

You probably opened a single page on Stack Overflow somewhere (or perhaps opened the mobile app or had a page open in a mobile browser that then reloaded automatically) that day, nothing more. You visited, but were not active.

Comment: I am 99% sure I did not open any SO link (will check again my history when back at home, though). My thinking is that maybe activity in Meta SE could affect "last seen" in SO because them being together until some months ago.

Comment: @fedorqui: no, your network profile is updated from your site profiles, not the other way around.

Comment: @fedorqui: and 'visited' may reflect a visit from *across different devices*. Are you 100% certain that you use just one browser to visit the site, ever? And no-one else uses that computer?

Comment: Note I am mentioning the Meta SE profile, not the network profile. For example in http://stackexchange.com/users/4879/glenn-jackman?tab=accounts I see "last seen 22 days ago", despite being present today in other sites.

Comment: @fedorqui: Right, but the two are not related still. A visit to Meta.SE won't count as a visit to SO either, no.

Comment: Regarding the visiting and the browser: could be, only that my presence in [SO] was reported to have happened more or less at the same time as I was in SE, etc (0.29 versus 0.30). It is this resemblance that make it suspicious.

Comment: Let's see if I understood the behaviour (I got a bit confused about what is what): "Last seen" can be just logging (visited), whereas to have a day marked as green in the calendar thingy you need to do something else (active). Is it like this?

Comment: @fedorqui: exactly; the calendar tracks days that count toward the consecutive days visited badges. You need to do more than just visit, but what that 'more' is exactly is not disclosed.

Comment: @fedorqui: I've been experimenting a little, I cannot get a visit to Meta.SE show up as a visit to Stack Overflow or vice versa. The timing of your visits is not *exactly* the same either, which is something I'd expect if a visit to one counted as a visit to the other.

Comment: Wow, this is in Meta Posts now. Yesterday at night I checked my history and no access to SO was done on the mentioned period of time. However, I tried to reproduce the situation and could not manage to make it happen. Thus, I guess it is kind of status-norepro, so I am accepting the answer. I will update with more details if it happens again! And, of course, many thanks for the information and your time.